# Solr Mulivalued Problem

Tags: json, solr, multivalue

Consider The  following is the json response  i'm getting from the  ***solr***  if i use ***multivalued = true*** for the fields.

```
  {
    "id":["1","2","3"],
    "TS":["2010-06-28 00:00:00.0","2010-06-28 00:00:00.0","2010-06-28 00:00:00.0"],
    "Type":["VIDEO","IMAGE","VIDEO"]
    }

but i need the response like this

    {
    "0":["1","2010-06-28 00:00:00.0","VIDEO"],
    "1":["2","2010-06-28 00:00:00.0","IMAGE"],
    "2":["3","2010-06-28 00:00:00.0","VIDEO"]
    }

How can i get this.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
```

> ```
>  **Update :**
>     Actually at the first level its not a problem. When we are going
> ```
>
> more than one level then only the
>   problem arises. right now i'm putting
>   the entire response here to make it
>   clear.

```
{
 "responseHeader":{
  "status":0,
  "QTime":0,
  "params":{
    "facet":"true",
    "indent":"on",
    "start":"0",
    "q":"laptop",
    "wt":["json",
     "json"],
    "rows":"200"}},
 "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[


    {
     "createdBy":"0",
     "id":194,
     "status":"ACTIVE",
     "text":"Can i buy Sony laptop?",
     "ansTS":["2010-07-01 00:00:00.0","2010-08-06 15:11:55.0","2010-08-11 15:28:13.0","2010-08-11 15:30:49.0","2010-08-12 01:45:48.0","2010-08-12 01:46:18.0"],
     "mediaType":["VIDEO","VIDEO","VIDEO"],
     "ansId":["59","76","77","78","80","81"],
     "mediaId":[24,25,26],

       ]},
    ]
 },
 "facet_counts":{
  "facet_queries":{},
  "facet_fields":{
    "catName":[]},
  "facet_dates":{}}}
```

look  at the mediaId , mediatype ,ansTS arrays. Its one to many relationship.But  they are grouped by column names.Thanks in advance.

Comment: who will consume the JSON? a browser?

Comment: yes.. may i know whats the  problem with that?,.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you will consume this JSON from a browser. So you can use jQuery or any other javascript library to convert the raw Solr JSON response into the  structure that you need.

Comment: if some values contain null then those values will be discarded by the solr. So it will be very difficult to assume the order.having not nullable columns is not a best solution IMHO.

Comment: @sathis: hmm, then you have a problem in your schema design, which is not related to JSON or how you process it...

Answer (score 0):

If the first snippet is the actual solr response you're getting, then chances are you have a bug in your feeder (connector/crawler/etc). It looks like you only have one indexed document (that matches your query), which has all the values that you expect from 3 documents.

Assuming you have 3 documents, analogous with your expected output, then the actual solr `wt=json` result would contain:

```
[{ 
"id":"1", 
"TS":"2010-06-28 00:00:00.0", 
"Type":"VIDEO"
},

{
"id":"2",
"TS":"2010-06-28 00:00:00.0",
"Type":"IMAGE"
},
{
"id":"3",
"TS":"2010-06-28 00:00:00.0",
"Type":"VIDEO"
}]
```

If this assumption is correct, then I would suggest looking over your indexing logic.

Comment: For multiValued fields, the values are returned an array (even if there is only one).

Answer (score 0):

This output is produced by Solr's JSONResponseWriter. Its output can't be altered via configuration. But what you can do is create your own version of JSONResponseWriter to produce your desired output. You can registered your new ResponseWriter by [adding a queryResponseWriter tag in solrconfig.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryResponseWriter).

Comment: no. that has nothing to do with JSONResponseWriter. Even XML  format  output also has the same problem.

Comment: Either with XML or JSON, Solr outputs, for all documents, all fields with its associated value (many values in the case of a multi-value). If that is not what you need, you need to have your own ResponseWriter. Now, if this is already the format that you want, and you think that there is a bug in Solr, I suggest first going with scdef's suggestion and make sure your indexation logic is ok.

Comment: so can i index an entity by referring it in schema.xml ?. if so please show me a example.

Comment: Remember that an entity must be completely de-normalized to work properly in Solr. See this link for some info: http://mysolr.com/tips/denormalized-data-structure/